# Flutter Firebase Messaging is Unable to create service io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to use Firebase Messaging in a Flutter app. I follow all the instruction from the package.

In my pubspec.yaml I have these packages:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  ...
  firebase_messaging: ^5.1.5
  ...
```

My main.app is just it:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

MyApp is a StatefullWidget and inside the _MyAppState I have:

```
    FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
   @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    NotificationHandler().initializeFcmNotification();
  }
```

All the code is inside whe notification_handler.dart (thanks to @HarishPenta):

```
...
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
...

class NotificationHandler {
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;
  FirebaseMessaging _fcm = FirebaseMessaging();
  StreamSubscription iosSubscription;
  static final NotificationHandler _singleton =
  new NotificationHandler._internal();

  factory NotificationHandler() {
    return _singleton;
  }
  NotificationHandler._internal();

  Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(
      Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onLaunch: $message");
    // Or do other work.
  }

  initializeFcmNotification() async {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

    var initializationSettingsAndroid =
    new AndroidInitializationSettings('ic_launcher');
    var initializationSettingsIOS = new IOSInitializationSettings(
        onDidReceiveLocalNotification: onDidReceiveLocalNotification);
    var initializationSettings = new InitializationSettings(
        initializationSettingsAndroid, initializationSettingsIOS);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);

    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      iosSubscription = _fcm.onIosSettingsRegistered.listen((data) {
        // save the token  OR subscribe to a topic here
      });

      _fcm.requestNotificationPermissions(IosNotificationSettings());
    } else {
      _saveDeviceToken();
    }

    _fcm.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onMessage: $message");
      },
      //onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler,
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume: $message");
      },
    );
  }

...}
```

In my AndroidManifest.xml I have:

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
...
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
```

and, finally, inside the app/src/main/java//Application.java I have:

```
package <my ID app>;  --> the same ID in google-services.json

import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;

import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService;


public class Application extends FlutterApplication implements PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry);
    }
}
```

Well, the app start OK, and, in foreground, when I send a notification, the app stop and I can see this error message:

```
D/AndroidRuntime(26933): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime(26933): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(26933): Process: br.com.htsnet.emergencia, PID: 26933
E/AndroidRuntime(26933): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService: java.lang.RuntimeException: PluginRegistrantCallback is not set.
E/AndroidRuntime(26933):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3167)
E/AndroidRuntime(26933):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:177)
E/AndroidRuntime(26933):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1532)
E/AndroidRuntime(26933):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(26933):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
E/AndroidRuntime(26933):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5951)
E/AndroidRuntime(26933):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(26933):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
E/AndroidRuntime(26933):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
E/AndroidRuntime(26933):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
E/AndroidRuntime(26933): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: PluginRegistrantCallback is not set.
E/AndroidRuntime(26933):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.startBackgroundIsolate(FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.java:157)
E/AndroidRuntime(26933):    at io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.onCreate(FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.java:77)
E/AndroidRuntime(26933):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3157)
E/AndroidRuntime(26933):    ... 9 more
```

I am using Android Studio 3.5, Firebase Functions to send notification whith data in paypload (click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK').

Comment: Did you solved this issue?

Comment: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/145, but the version is now 6.0.9, so is it still an issue?

Answer (score 6):

Add the below mentioned files in your android/app/main/java/com/

**Application.java**

```
package com.example.<application Name>;
import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService;

public class Application extends FlutterApplication implements PluginRegistrantCallback {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
    FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant.registerWith(registry);
  }
}
```

**FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant**

```
package com.example.<application Name>;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin;

public final class FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant{
  public static void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
    if (alreadyRegisteredWith(registry)) {
      return;
    }
    FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
  }

  private static boolean alreadyRegisteredWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
    final String key = FirebaseCloudMessagingPluginRegistrant.class.getCanonicalName();
    if (registry.hasPlugin(key)) {
      return true;
    }
    registry.registrarFor(key);
    return false;
  }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.<application Name>;
import android.os.Bundle;
import  `io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity`;
import `io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant`;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: Where did you find this documented? Thanks.

Comment: Also, adding all this results in:

error: incompatible types: MainActivity cannot be converted to FlutterEngine
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)

Just some standard documentation and/or just keeping SOME form of consistency on Android would be awesome. Everything works fine on iOS. :\

Comment: @ChrisH I've the same problem. Thing is that we already migrated to the new wrappers. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects#add-to-app-migration

Answer (score 3):

**Working**`

```
import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService;

public class Application extends FlutterApplication implements PluginRegistrantCallback {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith((FlutterEngine) registry);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you mind adding some explanation instead of only code?

Answer (score 0):

//That is working for me

```
import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebase.messaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundService;

public class Application extends FlutterApplication implements PluginRegistrantCallback {
  // ...
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
  }

  @Override
  public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith((FlutterEngine) registry);
  }
  // ...
}
```

// In your manifeste make sure to change

```
android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
```

to

```
android:name=".Application"
```

Answer (score -4):

Am faced same issue :  Just removed "Application.class" from android project. Code working fine.

Comment: Application class is needed only for backgroun message handling, so if someone dont need background messaging then no need to implement Application.java. so you are totaly right