# Firebase messaging - Notifications are not sent when app is Closed or sleep in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have built my app in flutter and I have implemented both LocalNotifications and FCM messaging.

this is my code:

```
 final FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();


  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    registerNotification();
    configLocalNotification();

  }



  void registerNotification() {
    firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions();

    firebaseMessaging.configure(onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
      print('onMessage: $message');
      return ;
    }, onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
      print('onResume: $message');
      return Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => NotificationsScreen()));
    },
        onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
      print('onLaunch: $message');
      return;
    });

    firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((token) {
      print('token: $token');
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Consultant')
          .doc(firebaseUser.uid)
          .update({'deviceToken': token});
    }).catchError((err) {
      //Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: err.message.toString());
    });
  }

  Future selectNotification(String payload) async {
    if (payload != null) {
      debugPrint('notification payload: $payload');
    }
    await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (context) => NotificationsScreen(payload: payload,)),
    );
  }

  void showNotification(message) async {
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
      Platform.isAndroid
          ? 'it.wytex.vibeland_pro_app'
          : 'it.wytex.vibeland_pro_app',
      'Vibeland Pro',
      'Vibeland Pro',
      playSound: true,
      enableVibration: true,
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
    );
    var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = new IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannelSpecifics = new NotificationDetails(
        android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics, iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);

    print(message);
    print(message['body'].toString());
    print(json.encode(message));

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(0, message['title'].toString(),
        message['body'].toString(), platformChannelSpecifics,
        payload: json.encode(message));

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      1, ' Hai ricevuto un messaggio  ', 'Controlla subito le Tue notifiche ', platformChannelSpecifics,
      payload: 'item x',
    );
  }

  void configLocalNotification() {
    var initializationSettingsAndroid =
    new AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    var initializationSettingsIOS = new IOSInitializationSettings(
      requestAlertPermission: true,
      requestBadgePermission: true,
      requestSoundPermission: true,
    );
    var initializationSettings = new InitializationSettings(
        android: initializationSettingsAndroid, iOS: initializationSettingsIOS);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
  }
```

I have built a function in firebase to push some New collections as notifications.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const fcm = admin.messaging();

exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore
    .document("Notifications/{id}")
    .onCreate((snapshot) => {
      const name = snapshot.get("name");
      const subject = snapshot.get("subject");
      const token = snapshot.get("token");

      const payload = {
        notification: {
          title: "" + name,
          body: "" + subject,
          sound: "default",
          click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
        },
      };

      return fcm.sendToDevice(token, payload);
    });
```

the version of `firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3` and `flutter_local_notifications: ^4.0.1`
at the moment I don't upgrade due to some conflict with dependencies.
In this way I got both notifications when an app is open I get Local notifications correctly and when an app is in foreground and background I get Firebasemessaging according to the new collection added into my firestore.
The problem now comes when I close the app or the app after some minutes starts to sleep...
I can't get any notifications

To start again to get notifications, I need to run again the app and wake the app.
This is a problem with my app because my Apps notifications are very important and users need to get them always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can on the [FlutterFire documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage/#message-types), foreground and background notification are handled differently by the plugin, so there are 2 thing you need to fix in your app.

First you need to prepare your Cloud Function to send background notifications as well as foreground, and in order to to that, you need to prepare your json to not only have a `notification` but also a `data` field, as follows:

```
const payload = {
    notification: {
      title: "" + name,
      body: "" + subject,
      sound: "default",
    },  
    data: {
        click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"
    }
};
```

Second, you are going to need configure your firebaseMassaging to receive background messages, like this:

```
firebaseMessaging.configure(
    onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
        print('onMessage: $message');
        return ;
    }, 
    onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
        print('onResume: $message');
        return Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => NotificationsScreen()));
    },
    onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) {
        print('onLaunch: $message');
        return;
    },
    onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler
);
```

And finally you need to create a handler that will manually handle background messages, following the example in the documentation you can do something like this:

```
Future<void> myBackgroundMessageHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {        
    print("Handling a background message: ${message}");
}
```

Comment: do you think is necessary to ad: 
Future<void> myBackgroundMessageHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {        
    print("Handling a background message: ${message}");
await Firebase.initializeApp(); // this line??
}

Comment: not if the app is already initialized, which I assumed it's the case.

Comment: Great you saved my APP and my Life!

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Comment: Please read the comment I have done because I got app crash and the error:

Answer (score 1):

Adding the Line:

```
onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler
Future<void> myBackgroundMessageHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {        
    print("Handling a background message: ${message}");
}
```

I got these error:

```
Nexus, [10.03.21 16:59]
[ File : app-release.apk ]

Amore, [10.03.21 17:09]
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService: java.lang.RuntimeException: PluginRegistrantCallback is not set.
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:4023)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:224)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1903)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7562)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: PluginRegistrantCallback is not set.
 at io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.C(Unknown Source:70)
 at io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.onCreate(Unknown Source:40)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:4011)
 ... 8 more
```

Comment: Try doing the proposed on this [community answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65922815/12857703)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60687835/12857703) could also work, importing `io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;` and adding this code to your `onCreate` - `FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);`